# Redirect 301 issue with URLs containing question marks

Tags: htaccess, url, 301-redirect

I'm trying to do some basic point to point redirects using `301` redirect 301 with a .htaccess.

All is going well but there is one type of URL that is not happy.

I'm trying to go from:

`http://www.greenshorticulture.co.uk/details.asp?productid=802&subcat=189&cat=182`

To:

`https://greenshydro.co.uk/hydroponics`

I'm using:

```
Redirect 301 /details.asp?productid=802&subcat=189&cat=182  
https://greenshydro.co.uk/hydroponics
```

But when I run the check on it I end up with:

`https://greenshydro.co.ukdetails.asp/?productid=647&subcat=347&cat=198`

Other redirects without the question mark in them are working fine, just this type is failing.

The pages that I am trying to redirect to are old product pages - I need to do individual links to avoid soft `404's`.

Comment: From the [Apache documentation for `mod_alias` (which supplies `Redirect`)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html): "mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)."

Comment: OK, so I found the answer in this link:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681215/rewrite-redirect-aspx-with-specific-quesry-string-to-specific-wordpress-page)

The code I needed was:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^productid=802&subcat=189&cat=182$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^details\.asp$ https://greenshydro.co.uk/hydroponics? [R=301,L]`

Strangely though this generates a `302`, not a `301`. Not really an issue as the page rank will be passed and the user will arrive at the right page, but would be good to know why it is `302` when I specify `301` in the code?

Comment: Whilst the directive (redirect) you posted is not correct, it's also not the directive that is triggering the redirect you are seeing. One of your "other redirects" must be doing that (eg. using a `Redirect` directive and omitting the trailing slash after the target domain will do it).

Comment: (You should also have been able to derive the correct redirect from the linked question above?) "Strangely though this generates a 302, not a 301" - If you are seeing a 302 then it suggests another directive is performing the redirect?! Are you sure the 302 is actually for _that_ redirect and there isn't actually 2 separate redirects (in which case you have a conflict)?

Comment: @MrWhite You are correct, there was indeed another directive at the top of the file that the hosting tech support had added and I had not seen. This was causing the `302` as `301` was not specified. However, I removed this directive and reverted back to using `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^productid=802&subcat=189&cat=182$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^details\.asp$ https://greenshydro.co.uk/hydroponics? [R=301,L]` - this gets the job done fine. Thanks for your help.